# Text box value is not printing using javascript in web appliction

Tags: javascript, html

I have created single page web application, i want to print this page. In this page i have used JavaScript code to print the page and it has many text boxes and i used one button to print the entire page but, if i enter some values in text boxes and click on print button, page is printing but text box values are not showing in printing page. If i use shortcut to print like Ctrl+p it will show all values in printing page

```
 function printDiv(divName)
 {
 printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
 var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
 document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
 window.print();
 document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
 }
```

Comment: `document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML` will not keep the values that user has inserted.

Comment: Please let me know which code should i use to print text box values?

Comment: Posted an answer below, please try out the same.

Answer (score 0):

`value` attribute of an `input` is not synched with its actual value.

So, when you do

```
document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML
```

you will only get the `value` attribute in HTML not the actual value.

You need to put these lines before the above mentioned line

```
var divEl = document.getElementById(divName);
var allInputs = divEl.querySelectorAll("input,select,textarea");
for( var counter = 0; counter < allInputs.length; counter++)
{
    var input = allInputs.item(counter);
    input.setAttribute("value", input.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

gurvinder372's Answer is perfect! This is how I used his answer to solve my problem.

```js
// Stores manually entered deposit dates for proper printing
var calendarDocument = document.getElementById("calendar");
var savedDepositDates = calendarDocument.querySelectorAll("input");

// Replaces all of the <input value=""> attributes with the manually entered deposit dates
for (var i = 0; i < savedDepositDates.length; i++)
{
  var input = savedDepositDates.item(i);
  input.setAttribute("value", input.value);
}

// Grabs the HTML code from inside the element with id="calendar"
var elementToPrint = document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML;
```